# Laravel + DOMPDF - Como faço para contar a quantidade de páginas de um relatório depois de realizar o download?

Tags: laravel, dompdf

Vi vários exemplos na internet porém nada que consiga a adaptar ao meu código ou então que funcione.
Exemplo no rodapé queria exibir assim. Página:1/30, 2/30 e assim por diante, meu `controller` está assim:

```
return \PDF::loadView('RelatorioPSIConsultas', compact('Registros','Empresa'))
            ->setPaper('A4', 'landscape')
            //->stream('relatorio_alunos.pdf');
            ->download('Rel_Consultas_Psicologos.pdf');
```

Minha `View`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Relatório de Consultas dos Psicólogos</title>
    <link href="{{asset('css/StyleRelatorios.css')}}" rel="stylesheet"> 
  </head>

  <body>
    <main>

    <h1  class="clearfix">
        @foreach ($Empresa as $cab)
        <small><span><img id="foto"  src="{{ $cab->emp_logo }}">

        </span>

        </small>
       {{ $cab->emp_rezao_social }}

        <div id="project">
          <div class="arrow"><div class="inner-arrow">Tel: {{ $cab->emp_tel }}</div></div>
          <div class="arrow"><div class="inner-arrow">E-mail: {{ $cab->emp_email }}</div></div>
          <div class="arrow"><div class="inner-arrow">Impresso em: {{ $cab->impresso }}</div></div>
        </div>
        <br>

        <span id="endereco">
        {{$cab->endereco}}
        </span>
        @endforeach
    </h1>
      <table class="tabela">
        <thead>
          <tr id="DescrColunas">
            <td>Prontuário</td>
            <td>Paciente</td>
            <td>Tipo de Atendimento</td>
            <td>Resp. Atendimento</td>
            <td>Atendimento</td>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach ($Registros as $dados)
                <tr>
                    <td class="Menorcolumn">{{ $dados->pac_prontuario }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $dados->pac_nome_paciente }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $dados->ate_descricao }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $dados->psi_nome }}</td>
                    <td class="Menorcolumn">{{ $dados->dtAtendimento }}</td>

                </tr>
            @endforeach
        </tbody>
      </table>

    </main>
    <footer>

    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Número da página com DOMPDF e LARAVEL](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/336910/n%c3%bamero-da-p%c3%a1gina-com-dompdf-e-laravel)

Comment: conseguir exibir os números de páginas, porém quero que ele fiquei no rodapé da página. como faço isso? meu código.. <script type="text/php">
    if ( isset($pdf) ) {
        $font = $fontMetrics->get_font("helvetica", "bold");
        $pdf->page_text(90, 30, "Página: {PAGE_NUM} de {PAGE_COUNT}", $font, 20, array(0,0,0));
    }
</script>

Comment: [Leia essa respostas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/86039/configurar-cabe%C3%A7alhos-de-p%C3%A1gina-com-dompdf)